# ExtJS Store add extraParams when creating store in view

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have my ExtJS 4.2.1 Application and Inside my view:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
    itemId: 'cboEmployeeNumber',
    width: 180,
    store: Ext.create('App.store.employee.EmployeeCombo', {
        // here I want to set extraParams maybe like
        // proxy.extraParams:{ employerId:0}
    }),
```

I can do that inside my controller:

```
onEmployeeBeforeQuery: function(queryPlan, eOpts) {
        var me = this,
            employerId = me.getEditRequest().down('#cboEmployer').getValue(),
            store = me.getEditRequest().down('#cboEmployee').getStore()

        store.getProxy().extraParams = {
            employerId: employerId
        };
    },
```

But how can I do this in my view when creating the store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a proxy when creating the store:

```
store: Ext.create('App.store.employee.EmployeeCombo', {
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'.....',
        extraParams:{
            // your extra params here
        }
    }
})
```